# Can i post a data to the url in Ethereum smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, dapps

Actually i want to create a smart contract in ethereum for handling the api requests. creating a proxy kind of contract which makes note of the number of requests in the contract.
Is it possible, any material available for me to refer...

Comment: Hi. Have a look on Oraclize: http://www.oraclize.it

Comment: You cannot do `HTTP POST` but you can pass values.

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look  on the last example https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-simple-query `oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://shapeshift.io/sendamount).success.deposit",
  '{"pair":"eth_btc","amount":"1","withdrawal":"1AAcCo21EUc1jbocjssSQDzLna9Vem2UN5"}')`

Comment: i just want to create a proxy mediation....